# Surd-like trinomials form a field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

This is a problem from Artin's book "Algebra". In the fifth miscellaneous problem of the chapter "Vector spaces", he has asked to prove that:

If $\alpha$ is a cube root of $2$, then the real numbers $a+b\alpha +c\alpha ^2$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ form a field.

I am stuck at proving this. For example, what would be the inverse of $1+\alpha  +\alpha^2$? In the previous subpart, we were asked to prove that $1,\alpha, \alpha^2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and that went well. Using this result seems to give me there is no inverse of $1+\alpha + \alpha^2$ in the above set, which can't happen in a field.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Well, $(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)(\alpha-1)=\alpha^3-1=1$, so that one is fairly easy :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks. It was really trivial. I guess I was thinking a lot and possibly ended in a miscalculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract algebra approach is to take $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and show that $f(x)$ and $p(x)=x^3-2$ are relatively prime, so there must be a pair $u(x),v(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ such that $1=f(x)u(x)+p(x)v(x)$. Then $f(\alpha)u(\alpha)=1$, and thus $u(\alpha)$ is the inverse. You can find $u,v$ since $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a Euclidean domain.

The linear algebra approach is to consider $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ as a linear transformation on the $\mathbb Q$-vector space $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. Then show that, under the normal basis $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$, that the determinant of this linear transformation is not zero, and compute the inverse linear transformation. Then show that this corresponds to another multiplication.

The matrix for $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&2c&2b\\b&a&2c\\c&b&a\end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant $a^3+2b^3+4c^3 - 6abc$. Showing that this is not zero (unless $a=b=c=0$) will require a number theory argument. It is enough to prove it for $a,b,c$ integers which do not have a common divisor. To show it, first show that $a$ must be even, then from there that $b$ must be even, and thus $c$ must be even.

And the inverse of this matrix is:

$$\frac{1}{a^3+2b^3+4c^4-6abc}\begin{pmatrix}a^2-2bc&2b^2-2ac&4c^2-2ab\\
2c^2-ab&a^2-2bc&2b^2-2ac\\
b^2-ac&2c^2-ab&a^2-2bc\end{pmatrix}$$

which corresponds to multiplication by $$\frac1{a^3+2b^3+4c^4-6abc}\left((a^2-2bc) + (2c^2-ab)\alpha + (b^2-ac)\alpha^2\right)$$

Later, you'll find that what is happening here is that $a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc$ is the "norm" of this ring, and that if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ are the three cube  roots of $2$ then:

$$a^3+2b^3+4c^3-6abc=\left(a+b\alpha_1+c\alpha_1^2\right)\left(a+b\alpha_2+c\alpha_2^2\right)\left(a+b\alpha_3+c\alpha_3^2\right)$$

Using that $$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=0\\\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_3=0\\\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3=2$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that is a linear transformation?

Comment: OK I get it. It's a linear transformation from the vector space to reals.

Comment: No, not to the reals. $V=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, and multiplication by $a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. @Paramjit

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks. By the way, for any nth root of a nth-power-free rational r, $Q[r]$ forms an n dimensional vector space over rationals, right. This is the same ideology you used while defining the vector space. In fact it forms an algebra, right.

Comment: Idea, not ideology. You have to be a little more careful. The space of the sixth root of $8$ is the same as the space of the square root of $2$, but you are roughly correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

$\frac{1}{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}=\frac{1}{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}\cdot \frac{1-\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\frac{1-\alpha}{1-\alpha^3}=\frac{1-\alpha}{1-2}=-1+\alpha$

this works in general

Comment: Not at *all* clear how to apply that "in general." It is possible to rationalize the denominator always, but it is usually far more complicated.